# How to change header of document

Tags: header-footer

I would like to ask about header of the document.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\newpage

Pellentesque at quam sit amet sem pharetra imperdiet a eget augue. 

\chapter{Introduction into optical sensoric systems long long}
How to do the header of the document with "Introduction into OSS long long" instead of "Introduction into optical sensoric systems long long" but I want to keep same structure.


\newpage 
\section{Short title}
Mauris ac porttitor arcu, nec euismod diam. 



\newpage
\section{The methods for polarization mode dispersion and their measurement}
How to do the header of document with "The methods for PMD and their measurement" instead of "The methods for polarization mode dispersion and their measurement" but I want to keep same structure.

\end{document}
```

I try to change header by `fancyhdr` but I do not know how to keep same structure. This is what I want for `\chapter`:

[image: I want to get the following for chapter]

And this is what I want for `\section`:

[image: I want the following for section]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE: Edited to put the mark commands after the sectioning commands as indicated by @Werners comments and with a new command for the section.**

Put the short titles in a `\chaptermark` or `\sectionmark`, respectively. For a chapter this works as the header uses the last chaptermark of the page, i.e. the extra one that we put after the chaptertitle.

```
\chapter{Introduction into optical sensoric systems long long}
\chaptermark{Introduction into OSS long long}
```

For the section this doesn't work properly because the header uses the **first** sectionmark, which is the one that is generated by the `\section` command. So we could put the `\sectionmark` before the `\section` command but this has two disadvantages:

1. There could be a page break between the `\sectionmark` command and the `\section` command. Then the **previous* page would get the section title in its header and the page containing the section would still get the long title.
2. Subsequent pages would still get the long section title in their header if there are no more sections. This could be overcome by also putting a `\sectionmark` command after the `\section` command. This becomes a bit unwieldy.

Therefore we define a new command `\mysection` with two parameters: the section title and the title to be used for the header. During the processing of the section title it makes the `\sectionmark` command do nothing. This does not support the optional argument of `\section` that can be given for the TOC entry. That is also possible but makes the command more complicated.

```
\newcommand{\mysection}[2]
  {{\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
    \section{#1}}\sectionmark{#2}}

\mysection{The methods for polarization mode dispersion and their measurement}
          {The methods for PMD and their measurement}
```

N.B. If you would use the `memoir` documentclass instead of `book`, the `\chapter` and `\section` etc. commands have an additional optional parameter where the header can be given.

Comment: Dear Piet, thank you, It works very well! You made my day.

Comment: Don't issue any mark *inside* the sectional unit, as this will make its way into the ToC, eventually also making the headers different there.

Comment: @Werner You are right. You should also give the original title as an optional argument so that this will be used in the table of contents. Or you can change the page headers explicitly in the table of contents. You can also put the marks outside the sectional commands but then there is a chance that they will be separated by a page break (not for a `\chapter` command as that usually starts at a new page).

Comment: Here is a way to get the table of contents without the wrong marks:
`{\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{}\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{}
\tableofcontents
}`

Comment: @PietvanOostrum: Disabling marks for the ToC will remove the ToC from setting these, which is not ideal. Rather set the marks *outside* the sectional unit. LaTeX ensures that there will be no break between the sectional unit title and the subsequent paragraph, so there's not a problem with being separated by a page break.

Comment: @Werner Thanks. I'll check that and edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Werner I tried it and it works. However, I don't understand why it works for the section. The problem that I see is that there are now two \sectionmarks: First one issued by the `\section` command with the full title, then the extra one with the abbreviated title. Now in the header `\rightmark` is used which selects the **first** one of the marks on the page, so it should select the full one. But it doesn't. What is going on?

Comment: @PietvanOostrum: Why should it select the *first* one and not the *last* (which it does)?

Comment: Because the definition of `\rightmark` is `\expandafter\@rightmark \firstmark\@empty\@empty`so it uses `\firstmark` which is the first one. To get the last one it should use `\botmark` which it doesn't. So I don't understand why it gets the last one.

Maybe we should move the discussion to chat but I have no experience with that.

Comment: OK, I found it. It **is** the first one. But in this particular example, the section title comes in the head of the **next** page, because the section itself is on an even page, where the chapter title is used. And on the next page there is no mark, therefore the last one of the previous page is used. If you insert another page before that section, then the solution will not work. So for a section the `\sectionmark` should be put **before** the section command, but then there could be a page break between the `\sectionmark` command and the `\section` command, and then it goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For comparison, in ConTeXt, you can specify the content of the marking and the table of content (called list) to be different from the title of a section head.

```
\setupheadertexts[section][]
\starttext

\subject{Contents}
\placecontent

\startsection
    [
      title=Section title,
      list=Section title in TOC,
      marking=Section title in headers,
    ]

\input ward

\stopsection
\stoptext
```

[image]